# Set a view at the bottom of a Scrollview

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, footer

I need to set a footer at the bottom of my scrollview:

```swift
VStack(spacing: dimensions.spacing300) {
    header
        .environment(\.mbContextTheme, .lightAlternative)
        .onTapGesture {
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
        .background(colors.neutralBg50
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
    ScrollView {
        list
        Spacer()
        footer
            .frame(height: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),
                                                to: nil,
                                                from: nil,
                                                for: nil)
            }
    }
    .frame(alignment: .bottom)
}
```

I had tried using `spacer()`, `geometryreader...`. Using geometry reader the footer goes to the bottom but the spacer becomes too high. I need that the footer keeps just at the bottom border of the screen.

Comment: use `safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom)` to keep the view at the bottom border of the screen. And disable keyboard avoidance with `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` to not bring view up when keyboard appears

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the footer *after* the `ScrollView`, inside the same parent `VStack`?

```swift
let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("header")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text(loremIpsum).font(.title2)
                Text(loremIpsum).font(.title2)
                Text(loremIpsum).font(.title2)
                Text(loremIpsum).font(.title2)
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
        }
        Text("footer")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.orange)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi! It's because one of the components inside of "list" is an input and, when the user taps on it and the keyboard is displayed, the footer appears over the keyboard (and for accessibility it's not that good).

Comment: However, I found a solution listening to the notifications of the uikeyboard, and hidding the footer when the keyboard is displayed :)